Use api key in query string aws api gateway
I've set up an API Gateway (using HTTP protocol)
Within this API there are various routes calling independent API services.
one of the routes needs to send an API key.
At the moment the API key is being sent from the client and produces something like below:
https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west.amazonaws.com/mystagev1/movies?api_key=xxxxxx&language=en-GB&pageNum=1&region=GB
This is routed to the service and works, however, is this best practice, is it possible for the key to be hosted within the API gateway, so the key is not exposed to the client?

No, do not ever add secrets, PII, PHI, or other sensitive data to the URL because it gets logged at many points inside and perhaps outside your infrastructure.  Instead you should add it as a header -- this is typical.
In the HTTP API Integration definition you should be able to append a header.
api-key=123
